# Java SWT application and Standalone Eclipse Help System

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am maintaining a Java application developed using Java SWT. This application uses the Eclipse Help System.
I have an Eclipse Help plugin developed and I would like to reuse it.

The current solution packs the help as a "Standalone help" as is described in [Help Eclipse documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fua_help_setup_standalone.htm). In this way an independent Eclipse Platform Runtime has the Help plugin and my application make API calls from its Help.
(The help works properly). The drawback of this solution is that a complete Eclipse platform is included (and distributed).

I would like to avoid the use of the "independent Eclipse Platform Runtime" and I wonder if it would be possible. I.e. I would like to avoid the distribution of the complete Eclipse platform which is in fact bigger than the application I am maintaining.

A possible solution would be to use Javahelp instead, but Javahelp uses Java Swing and my Application is uses Java SWT.

I’ve created an RCP project that calls the Help plugin.

- Would it be possible that my Java application calls to the RCP project and
  the RCP project calls to the help without needing any additional action like push a button?
- Another problem that I have observed is in order to call help plugin from RCP project, the RCP project needs to show its window. Is possible to avoid this?